# Finding historical London meteorological data

Tags: data-request, weather

Where can I find historical London meteorological data at a minimum resolution of 15 minutes (and not just hourly data)? The data needs to be from a station close to the London bridge. I found that St. James park station is the closest one but I only found hourly data, from here for example: [http://rp5.co.uk/Weather_archive_in_London,_St._James's_Park](http://rp5.co.uk/Weather_archive_in_London,_St._James%27s_Park)

Specific types I need from the weather data: Humidity, Temperature, Wind speed, Wind direction.

Comment: Please define "historical" a bit more in detail...

Comment: data from past years, for example 2015 to 2020